# Stack size too large error when compiling site from the Web Administrator

Tags: coldfusion, railo

I am attempting to compile our site from the Railo Web Administrator on a new build server we have just configured.  It has the latest installation of Railo 3 that was installed using the Helicon Zoo web installer.  When I attempt to compile I receive the following error:

```
(class: admin/applications/appbuilder_create_app_cfm$cf, method: _call000005 signature:
(Lrailo/runtime/PageContext;)V) Stack size too large, Error Occurred in File 
[C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Version120Daily\Admin\Applications\appbuilder_create_app.cfm:46]
```

The file and line number point to the middle of a large SQL insert statement.  I have also played around with the Java memory variables for the Java instance that the Railo process runs under with no success.  Currently the settings look like this:  `-Xms256M -Xmx512M -Xss1m`  However, I have attempted to increase the Xss up to as much as 128m.

Has anyone else encountered a similar problem or does anyone know what might cause this error to occur.  I would appreciate any help someone can offer.

Comment: You're probably better off asking Railo-centric questions on their Google Group: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/railo.

Comment: Thanks Adam, I actually already posted it there.  I thought I would post it here also in case there is someone here who doesn't look at the google group.  I am having trouble finding much information about compiling railo anywhere.

Comment: Ah sorry mate, I didn't notice your post there. I'm about as useful as a chocolate teapot today, it seems. Don't know anything about compiling stuff in Railo either, sorry.